# Measure performance rendering HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to **measure the performance** of browsers from my JavaScript  when they render the HTML5 Canvas.

To begin, I drew a simple 2D canvas and logged the time right before and after it was done:

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var start = performance.now(); 
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
var end =performance.now();
alert(end-start); //alert for testing only
```

This returned a very small value as predicted.

To mesure the performance I should render something more complex, So i did a code that renders a 3D image and animates it.

But now It's tricky to calculate time before and after since the animation is on a constant loop. I tried logging the time for the first animation before it continued to loop, but still the time difference is very small.

I want to see if I am in the right direction or if there are better practices. My main aim is to **check differences in performance between as many browsers as possible**, **using javascript**, and I thought this was better logged while doing a complex task such as renderign a 3D canvas.

Comment: Check window.requestAnimationFrame() to render time inbetween repaints

Comment: You could check how many loops of your infinit loops a browser can do during a specific timespan instead.

Comment: for general perfomance check the web for other solutions like 
https://github.com/v8/web-tooling-benchmark.
For a quick list of engines used in browsers (like chrome using V8)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine (has link to browser speed test).
For canvas testing you want to draw a big image on a canvas as big as posible to see diference in frame rate.

Comment: Chrome, FireFox and Edge (maybe more) have a `performance` tab in the developer tools which allows you to record the page and then shows performance results when done recording

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thank you for the suggestion but I want to do that through JavaScript code

Comment: @Lain Do you have more details about the coding procedure or examples I can check?

Comment: No example really. Just start the infinit loop (start = now) and stop it after two minutes (now-start=2 minutes), then check the amount of iterations (i). It is just a theory, so cant provide any actual code.